# How to get like count of an FB page in graph sdk (PHP)?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I've recently been working with the graph API for Facebook and i want to create a script that lets me input a `page_id` and will then return the like count of the specified page.

I've already taken care of getting an access token and logging in, but i can't seen to find anything concerning the total like count of a page in the Reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the API call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/bladauhu?fields=fan_count&access_token=xxx
```

You can use any Token if the Page is not restricted by age or location. If it is restricted, you need a User or Page Token of a user who can see the Page.

More information:

- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/